# Query inside "Object" column with Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Is there a way to query inside a *Object* column with ParsePlatform (parse-server)? Currently the Javascript SDK, as well as the REST API, only allows query on Schema columns.

Comment: I don't understand the question. can you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ArthurCinader apparently using REST API it is possible to query such as author.Name or author.About where both "Name" and "About" are keys of object stored in the field "author"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Parse by default, example:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"player.Name":"Sean Plott"' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

Where `player` is the field name and `Name` is the key in the object stored in that field row.